# Aliasing rows with hyperlinks when sending HTML table via sp_send_dbmail

Tags: html, sql-server, hyperlink, sp-send-dbmail

I am emailing an HTML table to users but I want to alias the hyperlinks for space reasons. Please have a look on the image.

Here is the `Sample1` of the image:

[image: Sample1]

Please see my below code :

```
    DECLARE @bodyMsg nvarchar(max)
    DECLARE @subject nvarchar(max)
    DECLARE @tableHTML nvarchar(max)
    SET @subject = 'Query Results in HTML with CSS'
    DECLARE @email_to_notify nvarchar(256);
    SELECT @email_to_notify = 'bens@ioec.co.za' ;
    SET @tableHTML = 
    N'<style type="text/css">
...
</tr>' +
CAST ( ( 

SELECT 
td = y.Customer,'',
td = y.ContractNumber,'',
td = y.Description ,'',
td = y.Market ,'',
td = y.BDM ,'',
td = y.EC ,'',
td = y.Reason ,'',
td = y.Link 
FROM (SELECT  FileReference AS 'Reference', Name AS 'Customer' , 
        CASE WHEN ContractNumber IS NULL THEN '' ELSE ContractNumber END AS 'ContractNumber',           
        'http://gateway.ioec.co.za/#/trade/files/' + CONVERT(varchar(10),Gw_File.FileID) AS 'Link'
FROM Gw_File INNER JOIN ... ) y
FOR XML PATH('tr'), TYPE 
) AS NVARCHAR(MAX) ) +
N'</table>' 

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @recipients='rajivs@ioec.co.za',
@subject = @subject,
@body = @tableHTML,
@body_format = 'HTML' ;
```

I would also like to highlight rows depending on value of the reason column.

Comment: If you want to format your HTML display, you have to (unsurprisingly), use HTML. For example `<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>` would be a hyperlink to Google, but only show the word "Google". Honestly, however, if you are trying to do things like chaging the formatting of cells based on the value of a row/column then you would be far better off using a tool more suited to such things; like SSRS. Unless you know HTML, you're going to find this hard (and seeing that you need to told the mark up for an anchor, I suspect you don't know HTML that well).

Comment: I tried doing this but the result shows this <a href="http://gateway.ioec.co.za/#/trade/files/1764">company</a>

Comment: Doing what? You haven't editted your question.

Comment: I tried using    '<a href="http://gateway.ioec.co.za/#/trade/files/' + CONVERT(varchar(10),Gw_File.FileID) + '">company</a>' AS 'Link' in the sql code  but the result per row showed the html tags ie :  <a href="gateway.ioec.co.za/#/trade/files/1764">company</a>

Comment: Were you ensuring that that special characters remained as special characters? `<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>` and `&lt;a href="http://www.google.com"&gt;Google&lt;/a&gt;` is not the same. I suspect you had the latter.

Comment: From the image below, my hunch is correct.

Comment: still not working, result displaying as 
 &lt;a href="http://gateway.ioec.co.za/#/trade/files/1764"&gtcompany&lt;/a&gt 



I even tried % to ensure special characters stay and got 

%<%a href="http://gateway.ioec.co.za/#/trade/files/1764"%>%company%</a%>%

Comment: I can't run your SQL, as it's not valid, but like I said, can you not use something else?

Comment: Try `SET @tableHTML = REPLACE(REPLACE(@tableHTML,'&gt;','<'),'&lt;','>');`. if not, without something to actually test, there's not a lot I can do to help you here.

Comment: Thank you the replace worked perfectly just needed to swap the gt and lt..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like that when you're passing your markup, you aren't retaining it's type. Special characters, such as `<` will be replaced with a string representation to keep the xml valid. For example `<` & `&lt;` and `&` & `&amp;`.

If it's just the `>` and `<` symbols you can use a replace before sending out the email:

```
SET @tableHTML = REPLACE(REPLACE(@tableHTML,'&gt;','<'),'&lt;','>');
```

This however, trusts you have no nested HTML.